# EF Core database update specify base version

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

In my projects I have two EF core migrations files in the Migrations folder which I have created based on the initial release and after an update. The initial migration ("Initial") contains many `CreateTable` statements, whereas the second migration ("Cleanup") only contains a few `DropColumn` statements in their `Up` methods.

My database was created by a call to `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` between the first and the second migration, i.e. I would now like to execute the second migration. 
However, if I call `dotnet ef database update Cleanup` I receive an error:

```
Applying migration '20190409043916_Initial'.
Failed executing DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [LongRunningOperations] (
    [Id] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Start] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [End] datetime2 NULL,
    [Discriminator] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LongRunningOperations] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'LongRunningOperations' in the database.
```

Obviously, EF wants to apply the first migration as well. Is there an option to specify the base version of the database? Can I do something else to avoid that the "Initial" migration is executed?

A more general question that might help me understand what's happening: How does EF Core determine what the base version is, i.e. which migrations must be executed?

Comment: Not too familiar with EF but most database migrations have a history table or something to track applied migrations.  Check and add that migration record and it should think it already applied it.

Comment: @JAZ is correct, the table you are looking for is `__EFMigrationsHistory`  and the `MigrationId` should match the name of your migration (e.g. "20190410160507_LongRunningOperations")

Comment: thanks, that's it. You can make this an answer if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My database was created by a call to `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`

That's the root of the problem. The documentation for [Create and Drop APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created) contains the following:

> **Warning**
>
> EnsureCreated and Migrations don't work well together. If you're using Migrations, don't use EnsureCreated to initialize the schema.

and then:

> Transitioning from EnsureCreated to Migrations is not a seamless experience. The simplest way to do it is to drop the database and re-create it using Migrations. If you anticipate using migrations in the future, it's best to just start with Migrations instead of using EnsureCreated.

Similar in [Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/index#apply-migrations-at-runtime):

> **Warning**
>
> - Don't call `EnsureCreated()` before `Migrate()`. `EnsureCreated()` bypasses Migrations to create the schema, which causes `Migrate()` to fail.

Shortly, you should have used either EF Core tools or `context.Database.Migrate()` for creating/updating database.

Since you did it the wrong way, either follow their recommendation to *"drop the database and re-create it using Migrations"*, or try to reconstruct the [Migrations History Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table) the way EF Core would have created and populated it initially if you were using the intended migrations workflow.